# C++ 'this' pointer usage inside class method

Tags: c++, oop, this, binary-tree

I'm porting a binary tree implementation from C to C++, converting it to a class in the process. 
Sorry in advance for the C way of handling most things. 
The attributes consists of

```
T data;
node<T> *left, *right;
```

I'm trying to make changes to the root node through

```
node<T>* current = this;        // points to root node
node<T> newnode = node<T>(5);   // just a test value
current->left = &newnode;

cout << "current->left: " << current->left << " value: " << current->left->data << endl;
cout << "this->left: " << " value: " << this->left->data << endl;
```

In my mind, those two prints should print exactly the same thing, since current and this both point to the same object, but the output I got is clearly different

```
current->left: 0x7fffffffddb0 value: 5
this->left: 0x7fffffffddb0 value: -139656192
```

So they point to the same left object, but that object holds different values when viewed differently, what gives?

---

**Additoinal Info** 
Declaration

```
template <typename T>
class node {
public:
    T data;
    node<T> *left, *right;

    void insert(T data);
    int remove(T target);  // returns success or not
    node<T>* find(T target);
    void print(int mode);  // need overloading since can't use 'this' as default var
    void print(int mode, node<T>* root);

private:
    node<T>* node_new(T data);
    void node_find(T key, node<T>*** target_node_address_handle);
    void node_delete(node<T>** target_address);
};
```

Constructor

```
template <typename T>
node<T>::node(T rootdata) {
    data = rootdata;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}
```

Find method shared by insert and delete

```
template <typename T>
void node<T>::node_find(T key, node<T>*** target_node_address_handle) {
    node<T>* current = this;
    while(current) {
         if (typeid(key) == typeid(current->data)) {
              if (key == current->data) break;
              else if (key < current->data) current = current->left;
              else current = current->right;
         }
    }
    // if loop exited without breaking, will insert into empty NULL position
    *target_node_address_handle = &current;
}
```

My insert doesn't work, but I'm not sure if that's a problem in node_find or node_insert

```
template <typename T>
void node<T>::insert(T data) {
    node<T>** target_node_address;
    node_find(data, &target_node_address);  
    // target_node_address should now point to one of root's decedents

    if (!(*target_node_address))   // nothing at target node as expected
        *target_node_address = node_new(data);   
        // node_new returns pointer to node
}
```

---

**Edit**
Copy constructor

```
template <typename T>
node<T>::node(const node<T>& anothernode) {
    data = anothernode.data;
    if(anothernode.left) *left = *anothernode.left;
    else left = NULL;

    if(anothernode.right) *right = *anothernode.right;
    else right = NULL;
}
```

Destructor (both added in declaration)

```
template <typename T>
node<T>::~node(void) {
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}
```

Interesting thing is that it compiled fine before I explicitly added these in...

Comment: What is the declaration of `node`?

Comment: Your code does not seem to be [SCCE](http://sscce.org/)-compliant. Does `node<T>` have copy-constructor and destructor? The line `node<T> newnode = node<T>(5);` means creation of a temporary object, copying it, and then calling its destructor. If you don't have a proper copy- (or move-) constructor, that may mean undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ooh k, I'll see what happens when I add those in

Comment: Your line: `cout << "this->left: " << " value: " << this->left->data << endl;` seems to not be exactly what you're using to display the output.  Given that this line has the 'strange' output, could you double check and re-paste what you're using there?

Comment: Copy and pasted below (I left out std namespace before)
`std::cout << "current->left: " << current->left << " value: " << current->left->data << std::endl; 
                              std::cout << "this->left: " << this->left << " value: " << this->left->data << std::endl;`
Also copy constructor and destructor added

Comment: Ah I think I see the problem now...
When I called `node<T>(5)` it returned a temporary object on the stack, rather than one on the heap with `new node<T>(5)`
I thought C++ automatically put created objects on the heap so I got rid of the previous malloc...

Comment: Your copy constructor is broken. You are assigning to `*left` and `*right` without initializing `left` and `right`. You don't need a copy constructor, the compiler-provided one does the right thing, and you are not supposed to copy nodes anyway. You should also never use `malloc` in C++ (use `new`).

Comment: "the compiler-provided one does the right thing" well, that's only if you copy nodes temporarily and never leave both the original and the copy in the tree. But as I said you should not copy nodes anyway. It's better to declare the copy constructor and the assignment operator as deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with new node and insert changed to:

```
template <typename T>
node<T>* node<T>::node_new(T data) {
    node<T>* newnode = new node<T>(data);
    return newnode;
}

template <typename T>
void node<T>::node_find(T key, node<T>*** target_node_address_handle) {
    // find node matched by key, or NULL pointer in correct location
    // give node pointer address back
    node<T>* root = this;
    node<T>** target_address = &root;
    while(*target_address) {
        node<T>* current = *target_address;
        if(typeid(key) == typeid(current->data)) {  
            //  assume comparison operator exists
            if(key == current->data)
                break;
            else if(key < current->data)
                target_address = &current->left;
            else
                target_address = &current->right;
        }
    }
    // if loop exited without breaking, will insert into an empty NULL position
    // else loop exited by matching/breaking, will delete non-NULL node
    *target_node_address_handle = target_address;
}
```

Problem was I was giving `&current` back to `*target_node_address_handle`, which would be an **address** to a pointer to NULL, rather than a **pointer** to a pointer to NULL, which I could change.